# MONO Server Freezing After 2 Days

Tags: c#, asp.net, mono

I've been having issues getting MONO to work on Linux and am getting desperate -- everything I tried to solve it has failed. There were issues with mod_mono taking 100% CPU on Ubuntu so I re-installed a clean Debian server and the issue persisted. I now switched the apache2 server into worker mode and am running MONO instances manually to better see what's going on.

Performance is better, and I no longer get the 100% CPU problems randomly when doing "service apache2 reload" or after a few days.

I have 5 websites. 3 are now running perfectly stable. The 2 more important ones freeze after 2-3 days. I then have to kill the MONO process and restart it.

The only thing in see in the log is this

```
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
WARNING: WebConfigurationManager's LRUcache evictions count reached its max size
Cache Size: 100 (overridable via MONO_ASPNET_WEBCONFIG_CACHESIZE)
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
Terminating connection.
Failed to receive record.
```

What more can I do to solve this? It's a very basic website, mostly basic HTML pages with a few simple forms. Either these 2 websites still have issues because of a configuration difference, or it's because they get more traffic.

This is the Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MailServer" value="smtp.myserver.com"/>
    <add key="MailFrom" value="aaa@bbb.com"/>
    <add key="MailShareFrom" value="aaa@bbb.com"/>
    <add key="MailFromName" value="Etienne"/>
    <add key="ClientPicturesFolder" value="~/files/client-pictures/"/>
    <add key="ClientRecordingsFolder" value="~/files/client-recordings/"/>
    <add key="AdminPassword" value="aaa"/>
    <add key="OntraportAppId" value="xxx"/>
    <add key="OntraportApiKey" value="yyy"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="~/error.html" mode="RemoteOnly"/>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.7.1"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="153600" executionTimeout="1200"/>
    <!--150MB-->
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="157286400"/>
        <!--150MB-->
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="RemoveDefault" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)/default$"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="RemoveASPX" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)\.aspx"/>
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="AddASPX">
          <match url=".*" negate="false"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
            <add input="{URL}" pattern="(.*)\.(.*)" negate="true"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.aspx"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note: Redirect rules don't work on Linux and are instead written with .htaccess but the other stable websites have the same thing in Web.config and work fine.

I tried so many things and nothing could get MONO to work stable on Linux. What else can I try? Note that if I set framework version to 4.0 instead of 4.7.1, all websites freeze after a few days.

Currently running MONO v5.10.0.140, and tried many different versions already.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similiar issues. Though my application makes a little more use of forms, DB etc.

These issues occour for me normally once I have around ~140 concurrent connections and the freezes occour very unfrequently and persist for ~30 seconds.

In the past weeks I troubleshooted them very excessivly and I could pinpoint it to two things.

1. Your application may not scale because the ASP.NET is configured to run sequentially. To disable it I recommend to add `<sessionState mode="Off" />` below `system.web`.
   This makes the execution of requests parallel. Though you may want if your application is able to do it, as you might create data races etc. with it, especially if you cache a lot.
2. Check your MySQL queries. Slow queries or other bugs might cause a freeze. If you load it to excessivly it might freeze your whole server. Also dead locks are an issue.
   After I resolved these issues I managed to completly remove the freezes for me, though these errors still occour in the log.
   I am still researching how MySQL affects the main threads performance.

cheers!

Edit:
So after some time I started to have the exact same problem. Depending on the load the server freezed after 1-2 days. (504 eventually just showing 502).

So I was playing around a lot with the settings. 
I eventually tried to use a different socket other than the tcp socket. Because as it turns out these error messages are thrown if there is a socket exception. Now Im using unix sockets and so far its running smoothly. 
I will edit this post once again in a few days when I have some data on how it turned out.

Comment: Someone else reported that it was an error on TCP sockets, and that switching to Unix sockets fixed it.